# Insulation of an unheated workshop

Tags: insulation, workshop

I have a small workshop in my backyard. The previous owner of has installed an insulation with mineral wool behind paneling on the walls and the ceiling. Now I have to replace the electric installation and that requires to remove the paneling. Currently it looks like this:

[image: Workshop with paneling removed]
[image: Detail]

My original plan was to replace the paneling or install OSBs when the electric installation is finished, but now I am unsure if insulation is reasonable at all or if should just remove the remaining insulation and thats it.

So is it reasonable to insulate a workshop that is only used from time to time and has no heating installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well..

1) If it's not in the way and not hurting anything, then removing it seems like unnecessary work. Besides the initial removal, there's disposal.

2) It provides some sound dampening...shop work can be loud and your neighbors may appreciate it as-is.

3) Where there's at least a 110v/15amp outlet, there can be a temporary space heater, and so that insulation could potentially provide some benefits in that respect.

My opinion: Keep it.

Comment: Removing the mineral wool and the remaining beams is much less work and less expensive than buying and cutting new panels or OSBs... But the other two points are reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the insulation. It helps diminish noise transmission, both ways, and it decreases draftiness.

Comment: For anyone keeping score, this answer beat mine to market by about 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Even without heating, insulation slows the change of temperature in the building, and that can reduce issues like condensation on tools.

Too late for you, but for a workshop/shed, if you have to replace the electrical, just put it on the surface in conduit, rather than ripping walls open.